# Why does my material panel look different?

Tags: materials, interface

Complete beginner here.  I'm trying to follow [this](http://www.blenderguru.com/videos/introduction-to-anisotropic-shading/) tutorial on Anisotropic shaders, but my property panel looks nothing like the property panel in the tutorial.  For example, when creating a material, this is what his property panel looks like:

[image: The property panel in the tutorial]

But this is what mine looks like, if I follow the same path:

[image: My property panel]

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.  How can I see the property panel shown in the tutorial?

Comment: First of all, go to - File/User Preferences. Click on Addons. In the search bar tipe - cycles. Close the window and now click on Blender Render on the top of the window and click on Cicles Render.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14131/599 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6831/599

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is because you are using the *[Blender Internal](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render)* render engine.

Switch the render engine to *[Cycles](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles)* at the top of the screen in the *Info panel*:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You're using Blender render instead of Cycles. To change it click on the option button titled "Blender Render" on the top info panel and select "Cycles Render":

[image]