# Shader nodes are missing?

Tags: shaders, node-editor

I have blender 2.69 and I've been following a tutorial on how to make text.

The only problem is when I go to add a glossy shader in the node editor it does not exist. Neither does the shader category.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It sounds like your render engine is set to *[Blender Render](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/blender_render/index.html)* (also known as *Blender Internal* or *BI*) in the *Info panel* at the top of the window.

Try setting it to *[Cycles](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/index.html)* instead:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the object of interest is selected in 3D View. The nodes in the Node Editor are specific to the object, so for instance, if you added a lamp into the scene and the lamp is selected in the 3D View, you won't be able to see the nodes in the Node Editor that relate to a Cube, Sphere, or other object.