# The interface to create material looks different

Tags: materials

When i add a material to my object i get an panel that is like the one from [picture left] but what i need is an panel that is similar to [picture right]. Why is there a difference and how can i get the right one?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my material panel look different?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6352/why-does-my-material-panel-look-different) and/or [Shader nodes are missing?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6831/shader-nodes-are-missing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch from Blender Render to Blender Cycles, top of the main interface. That's your main problem - You're working in the old render engine.

Then... You have to set up a bunch of nodes in the node editor - Specifically a Glossy and Diffuse shader going into a Mix shader, which goes to the mesh's material output.