# Trouble with UV Mapping

Tags: uv

I am attempting to learn how to UV Map. However, the tutorial I'm watching has instructed me to click the "New" option. I can not find that option. Also, in the menu rather than having color options all it says is "No output node".

The blender version in the tutorial is different to mine. Any ideas on how I can move forward with learning?

[image]

Comment: Hi. In order to get the best answer to your question, please only ask one question at a time. You are welcome to ask as many questions as you need as separate posts.

Comment: I don't understand. I was just asking where the "new" button was or if that doesn't exist, why there are no options under the "surface" tab.

Comment: What tutorial??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The interface to create material looks different](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100690/the-interface-to-create-material-looks-different)

Answer (score 2):

hi @anon Maybe you could point us, if possible and free, to "the tutorial I'm watching" so to better understand what you were taught.

But UV mapping is not strictly related to materials, as you show up there.

UV are a 2d representation of a 3d surface, and need to be associated with a 2d texture, in the same UV/image editor.

Maybe add some detail of what you did and where exactly you have a doubt on how to proceed... You find (and create/delete) all UVs for an object into the "object data" properties panel.

I add this answer to show you a simple, basic example here below.

It's a basic UV map of a basic default cube.

[image]

on the right the "Object data" shows the UV map in the list (more UVs can be added)

at the bottom, you see the "add new image" for that show UV map. Maybe your tut is referring to that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you MIGHT be using Blender Internals while the tutorial is using Cycles or vice versa. If not, go to the node editor and add a new material output node ( Outputs -> Material Output ), and proceed.

EDIT: My other guess is that, your on edit mode and need to be on object mode to add a global material to the mesh

But from your question it has nothing to do with UV mapping.