# Different layout of UV mapping?

Tags: uv-image-editor

I have only started learning in blender on my own and don't really have a teacher I could ask for help. I saw two blender tutorials on UV mapping for beginners, but found myself unable to follow along because of a different layout of the uv mapping. Both autthors of tutorials seemed to have the same layout, preview, surface and such. But my layout was different and I don't know how to fix it. Additional images of how it looks in my blender and how it looked in the tutorials[image]

[image]

Comment: The tutorials are using Cycles and not blender Internal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my material panel look different?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6352/why-does-my-material-panel-look-different) and [The interface to create matrials looks different](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100690/the-interface-to-create-material-looks-different)

Comment: In other words, look for a dropdown menu at the top of your screen, it should now read "Blender Render". Set it to Cycles and you should be good to go.