# Blackbody node is not in the node list?

Tags: node-editor

I'm looking for a node called Blackbody. I already looked at [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6831/shader-nodes-are-missing), and I am in cycles mode. The [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/nodes/types/converter/blackbody.html) says it should be under converters but it isn't there.

I have version 2.66a, that ships with my distro. Is this a new feature only in newer versions, or do I have to enable this somehow? I didn't see it in addons either.

Comment: 2.66a is from 2013, maybe it is time to move on

Comment: There's an up-to-date PPA [here](https://launchpad.net/~thomas-schiex/+archive/ubuntu/blender) if you happen to be on ubuntu (or a closely related distro). Note that the main PPA is on 2.8 now, which has significant breaking changes from 2.7x and is still in beta. If you want 2.79, there appears to be a blender-legacy repo as well.

Comment: Does "breaking changes" mean if I start something in 2.7 it won't open in 2.8?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not in a version that old. It's time to update!