# why does my world property look diffent from this one?

Tags: properties

Someone was helping me with ambient light and showed me this from 2.79 and mine looks like the second picture. Why?[image: Second]

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6831/shader-nodes-are-missing

Comment: Your using blender render, as opposed to cycles, I think