# BSDF options not availble in texture

Tags: materials, workflow, shaders

I am learning Blender and I like to search tutorials but on some steps, I need to use BSDF but I have this:

[image]

Is there anyway to change this?

Comment: Welcome to the site :) If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on questions which still don't have answers. You also may want to check out the [help pages](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) or [the 2-minute tour](http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour) to get situated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your render engine set to *Blender Render*. Set it to Cycles instead by selecting *Cycles Render* in *Info > Header* (at the top of the window by default):

[image]

See [How is Cycles different from Blender Internal?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5820/599) for more information.