# I am having trouble with the Meadow scene tutorial on Blender guru

Tags: materials

I got the grass essentials pack, and followed the tutorial, but every time I put the grass in as the tutorial shows, it is a grey color and does not change.  I also cannot change the density, it seems like there is very little grass there that is all grey.  Am I missing some button or something from the tutorial? The link for the tutorial in question is: http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/make-grassy-meadow-scene/

[image]

Please let me know if I have something wrong here. I have tried going through the tutorial several times and it continues putting the grass part in as grey.  If I just add the grass in to blender by itself, it appears as expected, and multi-green color.

Comment: We will need a *lot* more information to be able to help you at all, please update your question with screenshots of the viewport, your particle settings and other relevant things. Also consider uploading your .blend file and posting the link to that in your question as well. Make sure you clarify exactly what you want help with too.

Comment: I do not know how to upload the blend file, and I will update the question. thanks for letting me know that it needs more info

Comment: You can visit [**this meta question**](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/658/including-a-blend-file) for details on ways to include .blend files.

Comment: I uploaded the blender file, and at least on my computer the grass appears grey, and on the plain, I do not even see it.  Hopefully with the blend file, someone can se the settings I had it on, and figure out if I did anything wrong or tell me how to fix it.

Comment: AFAIK the grass essentials pack is designed for cycles, but you are using BI. Try switching to cycles: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6352/599

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the very top of the screen for the tutorial in question, you'll see that is made with blender cycles and you are trying to do it in blender internal. Change it here:

[image]

Comment: I see.. yes I think that fixed it.. thanks everyone who responded to this