# How to fix: no surface button in the materials tab

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders

I had a problem with my blender. In materials tab I dont have "surface" button, to make  something like Glass BSDF material and etc. Please help me, how I can figure out this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6352/599