# My version of blender is not showing surface, wire, volume and halo options for materials,

Tags: materials

Hi I am new to Blender and I am studying materials at the moment.

My version of Blender is not showing the attributes in full on the attribute editor. I can't see the surface, wire, volume and halo options, I can't see the diffuse and specular as such.

[image]

Comment: If I get what you expect (which might be incorrect as you don't provide images of desired output) Blender isn't supposed to show what you want as you search in the wrong render engine. You use Cycles, while those settings are in Blender Internal.

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6352/why-does-my-material-panel-look-different but the other way around

Comment: Hey, thx for taking the time to respond, actually my question was rather stupid, as i found out later yesterday, cos ... well, yeah, i was not realising that different engine renderers have different attributes.